# Рассылка попадает в спам гугла

Tags: email, php

Проблема в том, что гугл - сволота, ну не понятно мне по какой причине засовывает письма в спам, главное почему не понятно.

Есть мысль, что это из-за заголовка hostname, т.е. в заголовке указывается имя сервера, а не сайта откуда идет письмо.

Как решить проблему?

```
$to=''.$oplata_mail['email'].'';
                    $hd="Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251\r\n";
                    $hd.="From: название сайта(info@site.ru)\r\n";
                    $hd.="X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\r\n";
                    $subject='Заголовок';
                    $mess="<br>Здравтсвуйте, &quot;".$oplata_mail['nick']."&quot;
                    <br><br>Вы пополнили счет на <b>".$sum." рублей</b>.
                    <br>Ваш счет равен: <b style='color:green;'>".$oplata_mail['deposit']." рублям</b>
                    <br>Не забывайте вовремя пополнить счет в панеле управления.

                    <br><hr>
                    <small>* - Письмо было сформировоно автоматически, на него необязательно отвечать. Но ответив на него можно связаться с администратором.</small>
                    <br><small>** - Если у вас вазникла проблема, обратитесь к администратору через e-mail: ***.</small>
                    ";
                    mail ($to,$subject,$text.$mess,$hd);
```

Comment: `в панеле`, `сформировоно`, `вазникла`.. Вам определённо нужен редактор

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. Домен должен быть у гугла в приоритете. + DKIM подписка.

У меня реализована отправка через AmazonSES, сделана подпись DKIM — письма в которых указан мой новый домен в спаме. Если указываю в письмах домен на старый свой домен - все нормально.

Comment: Я уже понял в чем проблема. Оказывается моя ошибка в строке $hd.="From: название сайта(info@site.ru)\r\n"; емайл заключен в (), а надо чтобы это были $hd.="From: название сайта <info@site.ru>\r\n"; угловые скобочки. Работает нормально теперь...

Answer (score 0):

Долго боролся со SpamAssassin, и в итоге получился такой код, письмо проходит спам фильтр, с оценкой 3.9:

```
class mailTo{

    public function sendMail($email,$message,$subject)
    {
        $to  = $email;      

        $subject = '=?utf-8?b?'. base64_encode($subject) .'?=';
        $fromMail = 'admin@pane.ga';
        $fromName = 'pane.ga';
        $date = date(DATE_RFC2822);
        $messageId ='<'.time().'-'.md5($fromMail.$to).'@'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'>';

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8". "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: ". $fromName ." <". $fromMail ."> \r\n";
        $headers .= "Date: ". $date ." \r\n";
        $headers .= "Message-ID: ". $messageId ." \r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    }
}
```